# Open several buffers on start-up

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to force Emacs to open several buffers when I open a file **(for example, in `js-mode`)?**

[emacs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvaDK.png)

**You can see on the screenshot what I mean:**

> > 1. My JS-file on the left;
> > 2. REPL on the top-right ("`indium-run-node`" command);
> > 3. Inspector on the bottom-right ("`C-c M-i`" shortcut).

---

It would be great if I could do the same for Clojure-mode with another buffers **(my file on the left and cider on the right)**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is a link to an example where a function to do something similar to this gets defined:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/26970/2287 .   A function like that can be defined in the `.emacs` file and then the function can be called towards the end of the file, or called with something like the `after-init-hook`.

Comment: A function with a similar goal can be found at https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDesktopBackground